# Oracle Commerce 11.2 experience manager does not load

Tags: oracle, endeca, endeca-workbench

I have installed the latest version(11.2) of Oracle Endeca Commerce. I deploy an application and everything works fine except that when I click on the experience manager icon, it starts loading the content but it never finishes.[image: This is what I get.]

I tried reinstall all components again and again but with no result.

Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your `ifcr.log` file say?

Comment: Hi. I cleared the ifcr.log because it was to big and tried to access EM again in order to get and post the specific error log information. I access EM and... it was loaded OK. Last time I did some Flash, browser clean up and re installation. Maybe this was the problem. But I have this  now... when I change something in EM and I visit localhost../discover-authoring I see no changes. When I visit <hostname>.../discover-authoring I can see the changes. Any ideas about that?

Comment: That doesn't look like a Endeca configuration issue... it looks like more of a IP Address mapping configuration (may be in your hosts file, etc)

Comment: Yes. I will check on that. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to Adobe flash player installation. I was getting the same issue in Mozilla and Chrome but IE 10 worked fine.

Try switching browser and see. This issue is nothing to do with Endeca installation or logs.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I realized that. As I commented above, the problem was fixed after reinstalling/cleaning flash and mozilla. Thanks for your answer.